# Schematron xslt 1.0 Postal code format validation

Tags: regex, xslt-1.0, schematron

I am using schematron to validate xml.  I would like to create a rule to check for Canadian Postal codes (formatting only).  A valid regex would be: /[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d/

I can only use xslt1 as a binding.  I am using the Saxon xsl libraries.

If I was using this sample xml:

```
<address><postalcode>T2R2R2</postalcode></address>
```

How could I create a rule that would validate this in schematron?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Terry

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 1.0 does not support regular expressions. But there is a way of validating this pattern with a Schematron rule:

```
<sch:rule context="postalcode">
        <sch:assert test="child::text()[
            string-length() = 6
            and translate(
                substring(.,1,1),
                'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                ''
            ) = ''
            and translate(
                substring(.,2,1),
                '0123456789',
                ''
            ) = ''
            and translate(
                substring(.,3,1),
                'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                ''
            ) = ''
            and translate(
                substring(.,4,1),
                '0123456789',
                ''
            ) = ''
            and translate(
                substring(.,5,1),
                'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                ''
            ) = ''
            and translate(
                substring(.,6,1),
                '0123456789',
                ''
            ) = ''

            ]">postalcode '<sch:value-of select="."/>' does not follow required pattern.</sch:assert>            
    </sch:rule>
```

It's a bit cumbersome, but it works.

It checks that the postalcode consists of 6 characters and then checks each character in turn.